# Why trailing question mark in an URL is treated differently in J2SE than Android

Tags: java, android, url

The following line of code have different outputs on J2SE and Android:

```
System.out.println(new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/?"));
```

(I am using `java.net.URL`.)

On J2SE the output will be

```
http://stackoverflow.com/?
```

while on Android

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Now, I am aware of this being functionally similar since there are no query parameters, but I am curious of why it has a different behavior. Unfortunately, this breaks server side code (not mine, but a 3rd party app that I am integrating with) that is using `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') + 1);` in PHP to parse the request.

Comment: I'm not really sure how they are supposed to be different? no query vs an empty query string could be considered the same for all practical purposes? how would you check serverside that there was an empty query vs there was no query?

Comment: echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: Another PHP example would be: 
$query = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') + 1);

Comment: Seems like a bug in Android's implementation. Could you please report it here? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list If you post the link back here I'll make sure it gets triaged & fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have submitted a bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64547